# Magento 2.3.3 | unable to save changes on imported products

Tags: product, magento2.3, save

I just imported a few products in my Magento 2.3.3 Shop and need to change a bit here and there. Unfortunatly i cant save theese changes. After editing everything i wanted to change i click on "save" as usuall but nothing happens. It looks like the save button is out of function.

Does anyone have experienced that before me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento2.3.3 Products not Save Once Imported If Products imported using csv issue.

In database table named

```
'cataloginventory_stock_item'
```

column named

```
'use_config_max_sale_qty'
```

affect the save functionality.

While importing using csv as per magento import/export functionalities It must be '1',not blank or '0'. So if import with blank or with zero then issue arrise.

It determines if the default configuration setting for maximum quantity is used, and corresponds to the state of the Use Config Settings checkbox. Values:

- '0' means the value of the qty attribute is a decimal value.
- '1' means the value of the qty attribute is a whole number (integer).

Find the below reference.

- [Issue Ref](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23802)
- [CSV Options Ref](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-attributes-product.html)

Need to change value from '0' to '1'.

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET use_config_max_sale_qty = 1;
```

- [Working CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MsyaeKoDJd5UHB9DEe7glSekkU54oGxV)
- [Issue in CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=178u_5rh58WqLfJPd0YvCpYdf_zag7L7X)